# Combining different histogram into one Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, lbph-algorithm

I am working on facial images, I have different image patches I already calculated the histogram for each patch, now I want to combine all patches histogram into one histogram, I am trying the following code which is given below, but I am not getting right histogram, please help.

```
P1 = imhist(uint8(patch1));
P2 = imhist(uint8(patch2));
p3 = imhist(uint8(patch3));
P4 = imhist(uint8(patch4));
P5 = imhist(uint8(patch5));
P6 = imhist(uint8(patch6));
P7 = imhist(uint8(patch7));
P8 = imhist(uint8(patch8));
masterHist=[P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8];
[final, GLd] = imhist(uint8(masterHist));
subplot();
bar(GLd, final);
title('Histogram of Local Binary Pattern Final', 'FontSize', 14);
```

After running the above code I got this histogram which is incorrect.
[image]

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Histogram of each patch has value from 0 to 255, now I have 8 histogram, means when I combine into one, it has to show me 256*8 values in one histogram, but here it gives me all values at point 0.

Comment: just sum all counts: `P1 + P2 ...`, or do you want 8 individual lines in one plot?

Comment: I don't need sum here , I need the concatenation of these histograms into one

Comment: Really not clear what you need. Can you explain with say 2 patches and three bins what the expected output is? Say `patch1 = [0, 2;4 2];` and `patch2 = [2 0; 0 1]`, what should that give you?

Comment: I have 8 patches, I calculated the histogram of each patch ,it gives me 1D array, and same for all other patches, now I want the concatenation of these array/histogram into one histogram.

Comment: Actually these are the facial expression patches I calculated LBP and LBP histogram for each patch.

Comment: @FaisalSajjad: "concatenation of histograms" is unclear to me. Two options how this could be understood. 1) Multiple Plots side by side like [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) would create. 2) Having one histogram plot with different coloured bars for different data, [like the second example here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html)

Comment: @Daniel I need like 2nd option.

Comment: Which version of matlab are you using? If you are using 2014b or later then look into the [`histogram`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function. Especially the section on *Plot Multiple Histograms* in the documentation.

Comment: @zelanix: For images, `imhist` is the function to chose. It automatically creates the bins based on the data type range and not based on the input range.

Comment: @Daniel, ah yes, of course - it would be so useful if `histogram` worked with pre-binned data. I really like the way it can handle situations like this otherwise. I think you're right that `bar` is the way to go for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you are taking the histogram of a histograms, resulting in more or less meaningless data. `masterHist` already contains the data you want to plot.

```
bar(masterHist)
```